# Symfony 5 Form Notice: Object of class App\Entity\Epic could not be converted to int

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony-forms, many-to-one

How to properly add task with epic_id?

on this request

> curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"title": "test1","description":"jhgdsh","epic":1}'  http://localhost:8080/api/task/add

had an error

> Notice: Object of class App\Entity\Epic could not be converted to int (500 Internal Server Error)

TaskController.php

```
<?php

class TaskController extends AbstractApiController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/create", name="create")
    */
    public function createAction( Request $request ): Response
    {
        $form = $this->buildForm( TaskType::class );

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if( !$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid() )
        {
            return $this->respond( $form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST );
        }
        /** @var Task $task */
        $task = $form->getData();

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist( $task );
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->respond( $task );
    }
}
```

Form/TaskType.php

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('epic', EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Epic::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'epic',
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotNull( [
                            'message' => 'Epic cannot be blank.'
                        ] ),
                        new GreaterThan( [
                            'value' => 0
                        ] )
                    ]
                ]
            );
    }
```

Entity/Task.php

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="task")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TaskRepository")
*/
class Task
{
    ....

    /**
    * @var Epic
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Epic", cascade={"all"})
    */
    private Epic $epic;
   
    ....
}
```

---

Problem was with filter in form type

```
   `new GreaterThan( [
       'value' => 0
     ] )`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to add a `toString()` to your Epic class

```
public function __toString() { 
return (string) $this->//title; 
}
```